# Stitching audio in the browser

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm trying to find a way to reliably stitch audio in the browser. So far, I've had only moderate success. For example, I'm able to run something like (in the dev console for `https://www.audiocheck.net`):

```js
urls = [
  'https://www.audiocheck.net/Audio/audiocheck.net_L.ogg',
  'https://www.audiocheck.net/Audio/audiocheck.net_R.ogg',
  //'https://www.audiocheck.net/Audio/audiocheck.net_C.ogg', // Doesn't work
]
// create an audio element and add it to the document
const audio = document.createElement('audio')
audio.autoplay = true
document.body.appendChild(audio)

// fetch the audio files and convert them to array buffers
const buffers = await Promise.all(urls.map(async (url) => {
  const response = await fetch(url)
  return response.arrayBuffer()
}))

// concatenate the array buffers
const combined = new Uint8Array(buffers.reduce((totalLength, current) => totalLength + current.byteLength, 0))
let offset = 0
for (const buffer of buffers) {
  combined.set(new Uint8Array(buffer), offset)
  offset += buffer.byteLength
}

// create a blob from the combined array buffer and set the audio element's source to the blob
const blob = new Blob([combined], { type: 'audio/ogg' })
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

However, when I try with .mp4 files, it doesn't seem to work. Additionally, as commented in the above sample code, the third file seems to have a different encoding (?) which prevents it from getting stitched together.

What am I missing that would enable me to stitch the L, R, and C audios together? If the files were mp4 files, would there be other things I'd have to watch out for?

Answer (score 1):

The arraybuffer of an mp4 file would container the header information, so they would not concatenate..

You could use this function to convert into raw pcms https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData